# Make an instance of a class the extends a parent by string without duplicating logic in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have logic that is similar to this

```
// Define a Piece class as a parent class for the rook and bishop
class Piece {
  constructor(color, x, y) {
    this.color = color; // color of the piece (either "white" or "black")
    this.x = x; // x-coordinate on the board (0 to 7)
    this.y = y; // y-coordinate on the board (0 to 7)
  }

  // Move method, to be implemented by child classes
  move(x, y) {
    // TODO: Implement move logic in child classes
  }
}

// Define a Rook class that extends the Piece class
class Rook extends Piece {
  constructor(color, x, y) {
    super(color, x, y);
    this.name = "rook"; // name of the piece
  }

  move(x, y) {
     //rook moves
  }
}

// Define a Bishop class that extends the Piece class
class Bishop extends Piece {
  constructor(color, x, y) {
    super(color, x, y);
    this.name = "bishop"; // name of the piece
  }

  move(x, y) {
    //bishop moves
  }
}
```

How would I create a method that would allow me to create a piece by name? Is it required to make the method look something like this?

```
function createPiece(type, color, x, y) {
  switch(type.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'rook':
      return new Rook(color, x, y);
    case 'bishop':
      return new Bishop(color, x, y);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Invalid piece type: ${type}`);
  }
}
```

I would like to not have to do something like this because its copying the `this.name` field from the classes. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know I can do something like this

```
const pieces = [
    {name: "rook", x: -1, y: -1, valid: (x,y)=>{/*todo*/}}
    {name: "bishop", x: -1, y: -1, valid: (x,y)=>{/*todo*/}}
] 

function createPiece(name){
    let piece = pieces.find(n => n===name);
    //you get the idea
}
```

If theres a better way to go about doing something like this please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object that maps the name of the class to the class itself:

```js
const pieces = {Rook, Bishop};
function createPiece(type, color, x, y) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(pieces, type)) 
        return new pieces[type](color, x, y);
    throw Error(`Invalid piece type: ${type}`);
}
```